# Changing a table owner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to change the owner of a table:

```
sp_changeobjectowner 'OWNER.TABLENAME', 'dbo'
```

But when executing I get the error message:

> Msg 15001, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_changeobjectowner, Line 62
>   Object 'OWNER.TABLENAME' does not exist or is not a valid object for
>   this operation.

Answer (score 57):

The correct way to do this in SQL Server 2005 and up is to stop thinking about the prefix as an "owner." The [`sp_changeobjectowner` procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, and you should instead be using [schema DDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [current_owner].tablename;
```

To check the current "owner" (this may return multiple rows if you have more than one `tablename` in multiple schemas):

```
SELECT s.name
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = N'tablename';
```

Also be sure that you spell the object correctly. In a case-sensitive collation, for example, `TABLENAME` and `tablename` are not the same object, and spelling it with InCorrEcT CaSe could also lead to this error.

Comment: At the time of writing this hadn't been flagged as the answer. I had same issue as OP (was using sp_changobjecteowner) ALTER SCHEMA performed the operation correctly. Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Morvael thanks, the OP hasn't been to the site since late 2012, so doubt it will ever get accepted.

Comment: I tried the ALTER SCHEMA command in SQL Server 2005 and got the error "Incorrect syntax near the word 'schema'".  The command from the OP worked for me in SQL Server 2005.  So actually looks like 2005 is last version that allows sp_changeobjectowner

Comment: @eric can you show the exact command that failed? Are you sure that was all you ran, or is it possible the syntax error was actually from the previous statement? I can't think of any reason ALTER SCHEMA would yield that error in 2005 unless you were in an ancient compatibility level perhaps?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It was the only command, just "ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [currentowner].tblAlterTest;", but you're correct on the compatibility level.  Just found that it is set to "SQL Server 2000 (80)".  Thought about removing last sentence of my original comment since its incorrect, but I can't seem to modify comments, and keeping the comments around seems more useful than deleting them, so I'll leave all as-is.  Thanks!

Comment: Just used this on stored procedure objects, and it worked on these too! SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 6):

Your statement is correct:

```
EXEC sp_changeobjectowner '<owner>.<tableName>', '<newOwner>'
```

If the error happend, try to check who is the current owner of the table:

```
EXEC sp_table_privileges '<tableName>'
```

Comment: No, this isn't "the correct statement" and how is your first line any different than what the OP tried? EXEC isn't necessary if it's the only statement in the batch, and the error message certainly does not suggest that the missing EXEC is the problem. Please read this to see why you shouldn't be recommending sp_changeobjectowner: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177519(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I don't know you read all what is in the MSDN, I did, and here is: "object can be qualified with the owner of the existing object, in the form existing_owner.object if the shema and its owner have the same name." And it is working - tested, IF you named the correct shema.

Comment: Did you read the part in the big yellow note at the top of the screen? There is absolutely no reason to use this deprecated stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. ZERO.

Comment: Sure, and I agree, and it is good that you pointed to the other way, but OP asked about the error message. For what I wanted to point, why he could have it, and what should he check.

Comment: Ok, but your first suggestion would have absolutely no bearing on the error message whatsoever. All you did was add EXEC to the beginning. For your second suggestion, there is a much easier way to check the schema of a table without bringing "owner" into the discussion - it is an owner in 2000, but not since. You can check `SCHEMA_NAME(sys.tables.schema_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

To cover the case where a table exists within a constructed schema name like 'Common' (that is not related to a username), then it is the schema owner that needs to be changed.

```
alter authorization on schema::Common TO dbo;
```

That will change the objects within the schema to the specified owner 'dbo' and keep the table within 'Common'.

To list schema owners:

```
select db_name() as Db, 
       sch.name as SchemaName, 
       u.Name as Owner
  from sys.schemas sch
  join sys.sysusers u
    on u.uid = sch.principal_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Exec sp_changeobjectowner ''<CURRENTOWNER>.' + name + ''',  ''dbo''  '  FROM sys.objects WHERE type IN ('U','P','V','FN')
```

Apply Following Steps

(1)   Run Following Query on Sql Prompt
(2)   Copy The Result and Paste Again to New Sql Query and Again Execute

This is Change owner of your Tables, Views, Stored Procedures and Functions

Answer (score 0):

If dropping the table is an option, you can drop and recreate under the desired user.  Just specify dbo in the create script.  For example:

```
USE [X]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TableName]    Script Date: 4/21/2014 1:26:37 PM ******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [Field1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Field3] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

run the following query
EXEC sp_changeobjectowner 'set here object name', 'set here new owner'
go