# Migrate PostgreSQL database into MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2014, database-migration

I want to migrate a PostgreSQL database to MS SQL Server.
My PostgreSQL database is on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64).

I can backup PostgreSQL database using below command and it saves in `.sql` file. But I don't know how to restore this Database file into MS SQL Server.

```
/opt/netiq/idm/apps/postgresql/bin/pg_dump -U idmadmin idmuserappdb > /home/idmuserappdb.sql
```

So please help me to restore database of PostgreSQL into MS SQL Server.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) and PostgreSQL 9.3.4

Comment: "*how to restore this database file into MS SQL Server*" - you can't. It's a SQL script that contains Postgres specific syntax. You would need to edit it in order to be able to run it against a SQL Server database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Which type of changes I have to do?

Comment: In short: a **lot**. Some things might not even be available in SQL Server e.g. `boolean`, `json`, `interval`, enums, arrays or indexes on expressions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563846/easiest-way-to-migrate-a-postgresql-database-into-an-sql-server-one but I am not able to find solution for me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it possible to restore database into MS SQL Server via `CSV` file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am trying to change dump script, So can you please suggest me, what query I have to use for SQL Server in place of `ALTER TABLE public.af_resource_request_status OWNER TO idmadmin;` and `ALTER SEQUENCE configuration_item_id_seq OWNED BY configuration_item.id;` PostgreSQL query, because I am getting error in this.

Comment: For the first see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302456/changing-a-table-owner for the second: there is no equivalent to that in SQL Server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157356/discussion-between-user3441151-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please help me for these PostgreSQL query `ALTER TABLE ONLY configuration_item ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('configuration_item_id_seq'::regclass);`, `ALTER TABLE ONLY securityaccessrights ADD CONSTRAINT accrts_eliid_uk UNIQUE (fwelementiid, permissionid);`, `CREATE INDEX afcomment_messageid_idx ON afcomment USING btree (messageid);`, `ALTER TABLE ONLY ui_item ADD CONSTRAINT fk_uiitem_citem FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES configuration_item(id);` any equivalent in MS SQL Server?